# Track IOPS cost for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have an instance hosted on Amazon EC2 where the C drive has the following configuration :

Volume type = io1 , IOPS= 2700  .

I was checking the monthly bill and i came across the following cost :

`$0.0650000001 per IOPS-month provisioned -US West (Oregon) (blended price)* 
4,132.083 IOPS-Mo           $268.59` .

Then i started checking the volume via cloud watch  (average IOPS counts for each minute)  to understand when this IOPS consumption happens on a daily basis

[image]

I am confused about the parameters to choose while showing the graph (average ? , sum ? or what it exactly the way to proceed) .

Another graph i made is the consumption during the entire month

[image]

But this one is not helping as it is saying i have average consumption less than 200 IOPS  on the  26th  which is in contradiction with the graph above .

Do you have any better idea to track on the cloud watch my IOPS consumption with parameters that are reflecting the reality to help me make decision .

Comment: You should do a sum on the second graph. Otherwise its just doing an average over all the datapoints through the day. 150 IOPS average over the day is correct. Regardless it doesn't look like you are anywhere close to using your provisioned amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashboard was showing that i am not consuming the allocated IOPS . I then changed the configuration of my Volume to be gp2 instead of io1 . I did not notice any bottleneck since then .  You will notice that this alarm supposed to monitor the consumption of IOPS  called  `VolumeConsumedReadWriteOps (Count)` is not available for  volumes of type gp2.

Here is a [great article](http://dizzythinks.net/ebs-or-why-you-may-be-wasting-money-on-provisioned-iops.html#.VlgeoSsT-pp)   detailing why you may waste your money on provisioned  IOPS .